# About return value of scanf

Tags: c

my goal is to get a line of integers that ends with EOF.

```
int n,i;
 
while ((i=scanf("%d", &n)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

when input was a single ^Z
it ends fine,the return value of scanf is -1.
Like:

```
1[enter]
2[enter]
^Z[enter]
```

this works.

But when input is like this:
input:
1 2 3 ^Z
the return value of scanf ends with 0
and the loop doesn't stop.

so i trid input:
^Z
there is a leading escape.
" ^Z"
and the return value is 0
but when it's
^Z
it works fine.

Why?

Tried

```
while (1)
{
    i = scanf("%d", &n);
    int ch = (i == 0) ? getchar() : 0;
    printf("i:%d n:%d c:%d\n", i, n, ch);
}

5 6 7 8 ^Z
i:1 n:5 c:0
i:1 n:6 c:0
i:1 n:7 c:0
i:0 n:8 c:26

5 6 7 8^Z
i:1 n:5 c:0
i:1 n:6 c:0
i:1 n:7 c:0
i:1 n:8 c:0
i:0 n:8 c:26
```

so the ^Z is not read and not explained as EOF.???

Comment: scanf will return an EOF if, when it tries to read the input, nothing can be read.  Otherwise it reads what it can and returns the number of things it was able to successfully convert.  In the first example ^Z is at the beginning of the input so nothing can be read and an EOF is returned.  In the second the begining of the input is a space so there is input to read but it doesn't contain a number so a 0 is returned.

Comment: This is boring to read but helpful https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

Comment: Try `while ((i=scanf("%d", &n)) != EOF) { int ch = (i==0) ? getchar() : 0; printf("i:%d n:%d c:%d\n",i,n,c); }` to see more information.

Comment: This is presumably on Windows?

Comment: On Linux, you Ctrl+Z and you are stopped and pushed to the background frozen. So, you can''t probably test.

Comment: From an IBM Reference Manual for scanf(),

**Return Value**
The scanf() function returns the number of fields that were successfully converted and assigned. The return value does not include fields that were read but not assigned.

The return value is EOF for an attempt to read at end-of-file if no conversion was performed. A return value of 0 means that no fields were assigned. 


So, in the case with escape sequence, you have read a character but it was not assigned as you were expecting an integer.

Comment: So I tried input:5 6 7 8^Z, still the return value is 0, meaning read but not assigned.But it already reached ^Z and there is no escape.

Comment: On your machine ^Z does not directly signal "end-of-file".  I suspect a ^Z acts like an end-of-file signal when there is no input in the _buffer_ and acts like a "flush" the buffer when there is.  Try "1 2 3^z^z".  (No space after the `3`)